# Control brightness of LEDs using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm at the beginner level in VHDL programming. Recently, I would like to develop a component in VHDL using an application with 4 LEDs connected to an FPGA board.

By controlling the FPGA with a controlword/-byte the following functions need to be implemented for the LEDs:

The 4 LEDs should be controllable unindependantly in brightness 10%, 30%, 60%, 85% and in frequency 0.2Hz, 0.5Hz, 1Hz, 2Hz.

The chosen functionality should be repeated until another controlbyte is given.

Any help or hints would be much appreciated to solve the task.

Comment: This is NOT a design center. Write and debug your code and if you get stuck we will look at it.

Comment: http://www.fpga4fun.com/Opto0.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a pwm (pulse width modulated) signal to achieve your desired brightness. And this signal is then turned on and off in a given frequency pattern.
As mentioned by Oldfart this is not a design center. We don't have the time nor the motivation to do your work. I suggest you start coding and if you get stuck somewhere I'm sure you'll get help solving your issues.